how to slove Russell paradox in modal set theory?
I am currently reading Nil Barton's "Iterative Set Theory." at pp.42-45.
It explains that modal set theory resolves Russell's paradox, but I don't fully understand it.
If a set x satisfies the Russell property in a world w, stabability guarantees that x will satisfy x ∉ x in all subsequent worlds.
However, since the definition of x itself satisfies the Russell property, wouldn't x ∈ x be possible in the world where x is created?
It still seems like a problem, so I don't understand why it is said that it doesn't cause an issue.
here are system's axioms using in above proof :




https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068
